# Automapper ResolveUsing or MapFrom

Tags: automapper

I have a mapping definition defined as

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Calculator, CalculatorViewModel>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.TypeIndicator, src => src.ResolveUsing(new TypeIndicatorResolver()));
```

Should I be using *ResolveUsing* or `MapFrom(src => SomePrivateMethod())` ?

What is the difference between ResolveUsing and MapFrom when it comes to complex mapping.

The Resolver or Private method will go to the database and get a value.

Comment: What does your custom resolver do? If `SomePrivateMethod` is indeed private you won't be able to use `MapFrom` that way anyway.

Comment: At the moment its a private method but If I made it public then should I be using MapFrom or ResolveUsing?

Answer (score 41):

MapFrom uses Expressions, while ResolveUsing uses a Func. MapFrom only allows redirection of properties:

```cs
ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar.Baz.Foo))
```

ResolveUsing can be anything

```cs
ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => HitDatabaseWithStuff(src));
```

I'd use a Resolver class when the resolution logic needs to be shared amongst more than one member, or if I want to have the resolver instantiated by a service locator. Otherwise, a private method is fine.

Comment: ok. In this case, the resolution logic is to connect to the database and get a value which is then assigned/mapped to the dest. property. It is not being used by more than one member but it does a repository call.

Comment: `ForMember(d => d.Foo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Bla {Meh = src.Bar.Baz.Foo}))` seems to work just fine... so it's not just redirection or properties, is it?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh MapFrom only allows redirection of properties: meaning one which can be achieved using Expression, and not by Func.  your example new blah... is still an expression so it;s good.  But lets' see you want to do var a = new blah  {Meh = src.Bar.Baz.Foo}; retun somefunc (a); Then, this can not be achieved using Expression and need to use resolveUsing

Comment: @jmjarri that's clear enough from Jimmy's answer, thanks. It does not change my comment though.

Comment: From automapper 8.0, ResovleUsing was replaced by MapFrom. [updgrate guide](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing)